# Javascript mouseup and mousedown event

Tags: javascript, canvas

i am trying to drag and drop an image of a card on the canvas of the javascript but the mouseup event does not seem to be working even though it is inside the main(). Once the card is selected, it follows around the mouse but it does not seem to let go when i let go of the mouse. I also know that the image is repeated from not clearing the screen.

```
function main(){
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = "allcards.png";
var imgX = 75;
var imgY = 75;
draw();

function draw(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,97,129,imgX,imgY,100,100);    
}

cvs.addEventListener("mouseup", function(ev){
        greaterX = false;
        lessX = false;
        greaterY = false;
        lessY = false;
    }
);

cvs.addEventListener("mousedown", function(ev){
        if(ev.clientX <= (imgX + 97)){
            var greaterX = true;
        }
        if(ev.clientY <= (imgY + 129)){
            var greaterY = true;
        }
        if(ev.clientX >= imgX){
            var lessX = true;
        }
        if(ev.clientY >= imgY){
            var lessY = true;
        }
        if(greaterX == true)
            if(greaterY == true)
                if(lessX == true)
                    if(lessY == true)
                        cvs.addEventListener("mousemove", function(ev){
                            var offsetX = (ev.clientX - imgX);
                            var offsetY = (ev.clientY - imgY);
                            imgX = imgX + offsetX;
                            imgY = imgY + offsetY;
                            draw();
                        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Can't you use JQuery?? it'll handle all he glue code for you: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: @Lando OP is using Canvas and the Image that is being placed on the screen is created with code only. jQuery DOM selectors would be [of no help](http://jsfiddle.net/SeRcf/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`greaterX`, `lessX`, etc, are all defined with `var` inside of your `mousedown` function, meaning their scope is limited to the `mousedown` function only.

Therefore, it is useless to try and set them back to `false` inside of your `mouseup` function. You need to declare your variables in the main part of your function:

```
function main() {
    var greaterX, lessX, greaterY, lessY;
    var ctx = cvs.getContext("2D");
    //etc...
```

Now, simply setting `greaterX`, `lessX`, etc back to false is not enough, because the `mousemove` event checker inside of `mousedown` is still active. When you apply an event listener, it stays there until you remove it.

So, the next step is to separate the `mousemove` event function into it's own function (I used "mouseMoveHandler" for the name) and remove the event listener using [`.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener) inside of `mouseup`.

The `mousemove` function:

```
function mouseMoveHandler(ev) {
    offsetX = (ev.clientX - imgX);
    offsetY = (ev.clientY - imgY);
    imgX = imgX + offsetX;
    imgY = imgY + offsetY;
    draw();
}
```

The `mousedown` function (important part):

```
  if (greaterX === true) { //you need the brackets for multi-line if statements
        if (greaterY === true) {
            if (lessX === true) {
                if (lessY === true) {
                    cvs.addEventListener("mousemove",mouseMoveHandler,false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally, the `mouseup` function:

```
cvs.addEventListener("mouseup", function(ev) {
    greaterX = false;
    lessX = false;
    greaterY = false;
    lessY = false;
    cvs.removeEventListener('mousemove',mouseMoveHandler,false);
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvM3n/) with the solution, but not using your image.

Comment: I changed them but the same problem still persists

Comment: @CRS define `offsetX` and `offsetY` in the same way, and make sure that there are [no errors](http://jslint.com).